# MySql insert with parameters

Tags: mysql

```
set @id = 1
insert into table (col1, col2, col3)
values (@id, 'x', 2)

set @id = 1
insert into table (col1, col2, col3)
select @id, 'x', 2
```

Both are failing.

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: Not knowing how they fail... You build a giant single statement but you appear to want 4. Please edit the question and explain how/where you run these queries and what problem you are facing.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I run them on MySQL (Workbench, Toad), with same error. What is the point of your question? Syntax is same, regardless of IDE.

Comment: Yes, we all tend to have such oversimplified opinions with technologies we still don't master.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add `;` between sentence.

```
set @id = 1;
insert into table (col1, col2, col3)
values (@id, 'x', 2)
```

Or

```
set @id = 1;
insert into table (col1, col2, col3)
select @id, 'x', 2
```

See here:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5da0e8/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema**:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (COL1 CHAR(10),COL2 CHAR(10),COL3 CHAR(10));
set @id = 1;
insert into TEST (col1, col2, col3)
select @id, 'x', 2;
set @id = 1;
insert into TEST (col1, col2, col3)
values (@id, 'x', 2);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5da0e8/2/0)**:

```
| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
|------|------|------|
|    1 |    x |    2 |
|    1 |    x |    2 |
```

Answer (score 2):

add `;` after every query and take table name inside ``
`table` is reserved keyword

```
set @id = 1;
insert into `table` (col1, col2, col3) values (@id, 'x', 2);
```

Comment: It's of course not you fault at all but code in question is clearly redacted and we don't have any information about the problem OP's facing. For instance, if he's running it with a client library that doesn't support multiple statements your information will be of little help. That's why questions are required to have **real** code and a full problem statement (including error message if any).